# How to prevent react-hook-form from clearing on component rerender

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

My app has 2 different layouts for mobile/table and desktop

`Router.tsx`

```
        <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
          <Route
            path={AppRoutes.Buildings}
            element={
              <Suspense fallback={<LazyLoader />}>
                <BuildingsGridWrapped />
              </Suspense>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path={AppRoutes.BuildingsCreate}
            element={
              <Suspense fallback={<LazyLoader />}>
                <BuildingCreateWrapped />
              </Suspense>
            }
          />
          
           ...
    
          </Route>
```

Each layout is represented by separate component and therefore each screen within the layout  is completely re-mounted when the screen is resized. In my case it also means that all the forms (`react-hook-form`) are returned to default value

`MainLayout.tsx`

```
const MainLayoutDesktop = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <MiniDrawer>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          minWidth: '0px',
          flexGrow: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <AppHeader />
        <Paper
          component='main'
          elevation={3}
          sx={{
            m: theme.spacing(0, 3, 6, 3),
            borderRadius: '20px',
          }}
        >
          <Outlet />
        </Paper>
      </Box>
    </MiniDrawer>
  );
};

const MainLayoutMobile = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ position: 'fixed', top: 0, left: 0, width: '100%', zIndex: theme.zIndex.appBar }}>
        <AppHeaderMobile />
      </Box>
      <Paper
        component='main'
        elevation={3}
        sx={{
          m: theme.spacing(7.5, 1.5, 4, 1.5),
          borderRadius: '20px',
        }}
      >
        <Outlet />
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
};

const MainLayout = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

  if (isMobile) return <MainLayoutMobile />;

  return <MainLayoutDesktop />;
};

export default MainLayout;
```

My goal is to keep the input values when the window is resized. Is there a good way of doing that without having to persist each individual form?

Comment: It not only rerenders the components but also remounts them

Comment: @Konrad thanks for the correction. Updated the post